# Start a single node using the default configuration, and the client cannot connect

Tags: database, cnosdb

I think there is nothing wrong with my operation, but for some reason the client cannot connect normally.

### 0. Env

```
version: cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 721266b
```

### 1. Reproduce step

#### 1.1 Start cnosdb

```
sudo ./target/release/cnosdb run -M singleton
```

#### 1.2 Connect to server

```
  cnosdb git:(main) ✗ cnosdb-cli                                                                 
CnosDB CLI v2.4.0
Input arguments: CliArgs { subcommand: None, host: "localhost", port: 8902, user: "root", password: None, private_key_path: None, database: "public", tenant: "cnosdb", precision: None, target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None, data_path: None, receive_data_encoding: None, send_data_encoding: None, file: [], rc: None, format: Table, quiet: false, write_line_protocol: None, use_ssl: false, use_unsafe_ssl: false, cacert: [], chunked: false, error_stop: false, process_cli_command: false }
public ❯ \d
error sending request for url (http://localhost:8902/api/v1/sql?tenant=cnosdb&db=public&chunked=false): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 61)
```

#### 1.3 Check log

Through the log check, the server part does not print the log of the relevant service port.log as follow:

```
➜  cnosdb git:(main) ✗ sudo ./target/release/cnosdb run  -M singleton
[global]
node_id = 1001
host = 'localhost'
cluster_name = 'cluster_xxx'
store_metrics = true

[deployment]
mode = 'query_tskv'
cpu = 8
memory = 16

[meta]
service_addr = ['127.0.0.1:8901']
report_time_interval_secs = 30

[query]
max_server_connections = 10240
query_sql_limit = 16777216
write_sql_limit = 167772160
auth_enabled = false
read_timeout_ms = 3000
write_timeout_ms = 3000
stream_trigger_cpu = 1
stream_executor_cpu = 2

[storage]
path = '/var/lib/cnosdb/data'
max_summary_size = '128M'
base_file_size = '16M'
flush_req_channel_cap = 16
max_cached_readers = 32
max_level = 4
compact_trigger_file_num = 4
compact_trigger_cold_duration = '1h'
max_compact_size = '2G'
max_concurrent_compaction = 4
strict_write = false
reserve_space = '0'

[wal]
enabled = true
path = '/var/lib/cnosdb/wal'
wal_req_channel_cap = 64
max_file_size = '1G'
flush_trigger_total_file_size = '2G'
sync = false
sync_interval = '0'

[cache]
max_buffer_size = '128M'
partition = 8

[log]
level = 'info'
path = '/var/log/cnosdb'

[security]

[service]
grpc_enable_gzip = false
enable_report = true
...
```